# unable to populate combobox using .rowsource {vba excel}

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I'am a newbie in VBA excel and trying here to populate a combobox in a userform with data from a sheet. I defined address & used the .rowsource property wherein code go through without any error but nothing populates on the combobox. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the code -

Private Sub empSearchdb_Click()

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim empSearchKeyword As String

'Stop screen flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'setting worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("EmployeeDetails")
ws1.Activate

'find last empty row
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 2

'when nothing is selected
If Me.empSearchL.ListIndex = -1 Then

    'from $A$1 to $J$lastrow-1
    Set rng = Range("$A$1", Cells(emptyRow - 1, 10))

    With Me.empDetails
        .RowSource = rng.Address
    End With
```

**New modified code -**

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim empSearchKeyword As String

'Stop screen flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'setting worksheet
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("EmployeeDetails")

'find last empty row
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 2

'from $A$1 to $J$lastrow-1
Set rng = ws1.Range("$A$1", ws1.Cells(emptyRow - 1, 10))
Set rng = ws1.Range("$A$1", "$J$10")


'With your listbox do the following
If Me.empSearchL.ListIndex = -1 Then
    With Me.empDetails
        'If nothing is selected, add a row source
        .ColumnCount = 10 'Otherwise you will only get 1 column
        .RowSource = rng.Address
    End With
End if
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Do you actually have an `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after the code ends? You should at least show until `End If`

Comment: @Noceo Yep I had `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. Sorry for incomplete code though I have two more  if conditions for list indexes but I am concerned about only `List Index = -1`. So this code will do, just an `End If` missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I have removed by answer, as I had not understood the question correctly.

Comment: I need result in a combobox named `empDetails` & `empSearchL` is my list box from where i select the criteria. So in short if nothings selected in `empSearchL` and user clicks Search then its should show everything on the combobox. I tried the above code but still it shows empty combobox. I've added the modified code below.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a listbox, my mistake. You could add prefixes to you controls. Using MS standards that would be `cboEmpDetails` and `lstEmpSearch`.

Comment: So if nothing is selected in the listbox, you want the combo box (drop down) to show all 100 items? That is a lot(!). And what if something is selected in the listbox, then what should be shown in the combo box?

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the MS coding standards. As far as listbox is concerned yes I want all the data. Well if list item (criteria) is selected then user need to enter the value to search where I fetch only one row using `.value` property of combobox manually. (e.g. I can search by ID or Name). So if I'am able to figure out the `.listbox  = -1 ` then we can use the same for other conditions.

Comment: But the new updated code which you suggested also gives nothing in combobox. I've updated it above on the question.

Comment: I know. I thought you wanted to populate the listbox, based on the selection in the combobox, not the other way around. I still cannot figure out, what options you have in the listbox, and how they affect the options in the combobox.